WP All Import sizes_stock
I'm new here and would be grateful for any help. I want to upload csv but can't set stock per size.
I have the following data and don't know how and where to set and if I should use a code. Can someone help me.
sizes_stock : L:5,M:5,S:5,XL:5
How can I set it so that the customer can select the size on the page and the system recognises the number of pieces by itself and does not allow more to be selected than is available.
Many thanks for your help or can someone take over.
I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know my way around

Refer to plugin documentation - https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/import-variable-products-woocommerce/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
